# Print the last line above the command, only if the line starts with "#" and there is no space or tab before it

Tags: shell, sed, grep, ksh

I would like to print the last line above the command, only if the line starts with "#" and there is no space or tab before it, even if there is an empty line between the command and the line that starts with "#".

Example:

```
#!/bin/ksh
# foobar1
   # foobar2
my command here to print the line above which starts with #


# another foobar

sleep 1
    if [ "1" -eq "1" ]; do
         sleep 1
         my command here to print the line above which starts with #
    fi
```

Expected output:

```
# foobar1
# another foobar
```

I asked ChatGPT to solve this issue, but this below command doesn't work if there is an empty line between the #line and the command:

```
grep -B1 '^[^#]' $0 | head -1
```

Comment: `print the last line above the command`: What is your command string?

Comment: @anubhava I would like to insert the correct code here by replacing it: "my command here to print the line above which starts with #"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `awk` command line this:

```bash
#!/bin/ksh

lastComment() {
   awk -v n=$1 '/^#/ {s = $0; next} s && n == NR {print s; exit}' "$0"
}
# foobar1
   # foobar2
lastComment $LINENO

# another foobar

sleep 1
if [ "1" -eq "1" ]; then
   sleep 1
   lastComment $LINENO
fi
```

Now if you run this script as:

```bash
ksh script.ksh
```

You will get output as:

```bash
# foobar1
# another foobar
```

Note that we are using internal shell variable `$LINENO` here that points to current line number of the script. Using that variable we print most recent commented line when `NR` is equal to `$LINENO`.

PS: Will `ChatGPT` ever be able to solve problem like this, I doubt :-)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n 'N;/^#/P;D' file
```

Open a two line window and print the first line of the window if it begins `#`.

N.B. This will also print `#!/bin/ksh` as it fits the criteria.